# What's wrong with my CodeIgniter SQL simple Query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I just have a little question about a query making me crazy.
I'm working with CI, and tis is the first time i'm using this great framework

1—
Okay so I have an insert query working rather well :

```
$data = array(

 'nom' => $nom,
 'prenom' => $prenom,
 'login' => $prenom.' '.$nom,
 'password' => 'facebook',
 'email' => $fb_data['me']['email'],
 'mobile' => "00",
 'etat' => "1",
 'role' => "1",
 'ville' => 'ville actuelle',
 'facebook_id' => $fb_data['uid'],     
);

$this->db->insert('membre', $data);
```

And I don’t understand why it always insert the data twice ... !

2—
Then I got a second question :
I just wanna found a user with the related facebook_id so i try that :

```
$this->db->select('nom');
$this->db->from('membre');
$this->db->where('facebook_id',$fb_data['uid']);
$resultat=$this->db->get();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($resultat);
echo '</pre>';
```

I’ve also tried :

```
$resultat2 = $this->db->get_where('membre',array('facebook_id' => $fb_data['uid']));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($resultat2);
echo '</pre>';
```

But in both case, the only array I got is :

```
CI_DB_mysql_result Object
(
  [conn_id] => Resource id #36
  [result_id] => Resource id #61
  [result_array] => Array
      (
      )

  [result_object] => Array
      (
      )

  [custom_result_object] => Array
      (
      )

  [current_row] => 0
  [num_rows] => 1
  [row_data] =>
)
```

So the [result_id] is okay, but there is no data (as far as it is supposed to be printed in [row_data] ?) When I simply try on mysql i got the right result with the right member. But with CI, it doesn’t seems to work.

3—
Furthermore, when i Try something like that :

```
echo $resultat['nom'];
```

it isn’t considered as an array ..

So .. yeah, I don’t really understand .. If anyone could enlight me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to use the result() method at the end, otherwise you only get resource. Like this:

```
$resultat2 = $this->db->get_where('membre',array('facebook_id' => $fb_data['uid']))->result();
```

This answers the second and third questions, as for the first I'd need to see how are you calling it - the code looks okay and my bet is you're probably somehow calling it twice.

Answer (score 0):

1 - are you sure you don't call `insert(...)` twice? Maybe you can use `$this->db->last_query()` to see the result query.

Answer (score 0):

for 2 and 3

that will be work with you

```
$this->db->select('nom');
$this->db->from('membre');
$query = $this->db->get_where('facebook_id',$fb_data['uid']);
$row= $result->row();

echo '<pre>';
echo'$row->uid'; // that will prent user id , you can change to what ever you want ex.  i want tp prent username it will be like this $row->username it should be same as database column 
echo '</pre>';
```